# Subclassing UIFont

Tags: ios, swift, text, ios9, uifont

Is it possible to subclass `UIFont` and initialize it with another one (or a font descriptor)? The problem is, I can't call `super.init(descriptor:size:)` for initialization because it's a convenience initializer. The purpose of doing this is to change the attributes for `ascender` and `descender` (override the read-only properties) due to the fact that I only display numbers and there's too much whitespace above and below the letters (which I draw directly in a graphics context). When there is another elegant solution, it would be very welcome.

I appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

What you're asking for breaks encapsulation, and perhaps doesn't make sense either.

Rather than using inheritance, and with a few assumptions,  a tidier way of achieving this would be to add a [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) to `UIFont` and provide your own convenience factory (e.g. class) method.

```
@interface UIFont (MyUIFont)

@property (assign) CGFloat ascender;
@property (assign) CGFloat descender;

+(instancetype) UIFontWithLessSpacing;

@end

@implementation UIFont (MyUIFont)

+(instancetype) UIFontWithLessSpacing
{
    UIFont *font = [UIFontWIthName:@"MyFont" size:12.0f];
    font.ascender = 0.0;
    font.descender = 0.0;
    return font;
}
```

There are caveats:

- That `UIFont` actually responds to selectors `setAscender` and `setDescender` - they are hidden on the public interface
- That setting these properties has an effect on layout and that conversely it doesn't have unwanted side effects.
- You're poking around in a black-box with no guarantees that what you do will work, or will continue to work.